# SQL tricky Nested request

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin

i'm working on a school project which consist of doing a facebook like application in php, and i'm having some trouble with one tricky SQL request.

My DB configuration is like this :

[image]

I want to get the friends of my friend that arent already in my list of friend in order to recommend them,

My SQL request to get my list of friend work properly so what im doing is that i'm looping all my friend, and i select their friend but here,
i dont know how to select them without selecting friend that are already my friend

Here is how i loop through each friend:
(i dont think this is the good way of doing this)

```
<?php
function recommendation($id)
{
    global $pdo;
    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM user u
                   LEFT JOIN friends f on u.id = f.iduser
            WHERE isvalidate = 1
              AND ((f.iduser = ? AND u.id != ?) OR ((f.idfriend = ? AND u.id != ?)))
            GROUP BY u.id";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id, $id, $id, $id));
    echo "<p>Vous connaisser peut etre:</p>
            <ul id ='recommendation'>";
    $amiscommun = array();

    while ($line = $q->fetch()) {
        //recupération de la liste des amis
        //Pour chaque amis recupération de leur liste d'amis egalement
        $sql = "SELECT *
                FROM user u
                       LEFT JOIN friends f on u.id = f.iduser
                WHERE isvalidate = 1
                  AND (((f.iduser = ? AND u.id != ?) OR ((f.idfriend = ? AND u.id != ?)))
                  AND ((f.iduser = ? AND u.id != ?) OR ((f.idfriend = ? AND u.id != ?))))
                  AND (f.iduser != (SELECT * FROM))
                GROUP BY u.id";
        $q2 = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q2->execute(array($line['id'], $line['id'], $line['id'], $line['id'], $line['id'], $id, $line['id'], $id));

        $amis = array();
        while ($line2 = $q2->fetch()) {
            echo "<li>" . $line2['login'] . " est un amis de " . $line['login'] . "</li>";
            $amis[$line['login']][] = array($line2['login']);

            $amiscommunnbr[$line2['login']][] = $line['login'];
            //Stockage a chaque iteration de boucle des amis commun dans un tableau
        }
    }
    $newarray = $amiscommunnbr;

    if (!empty($newarray)) {
        foreach ($newarray as $key => $value) {

            $nbr = count($value);
            echo "<li><a href='index.php?action=bio?" . $key . "'>" . $key . "</a>- " . $nbr . " Amis en commun(";
            foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {

                echo "<a href='index.php?action=bio?" . $value2 . "'>" . $value2 . "</a>";

            }
            echo ")</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: `AND (f.iduser !=(SELECT * FROM) )` - Is that even valid? or some guru SQL stuff  I don't know about?

Comment: Using `SELECT *... GROUP BY u.id` can be asking for invalid data because it's not ANSI SQL GROUP BY standard valid.. You are trusting here on the extended MySQL GROUP BY "feature" and [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) to get the correct matching data for the columns which are not in the `GROUP BY` clause.. Besides `GROUP BY` should not be used to "unduplicate"  `DISTINCT` is meant for that.. To bad MySQL does not supports  `SELECT DISTINCT ON(id), *` (PostgreSQL syntax) which is basiclly what you want here.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes it doesn work in fact it's where i think i miss the request to check if it is a friend of mine or not

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes you re right i've should used DISTINCT but has you said it doesnt work on a specific column, thanks you

Comment: ["hack"](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ioddCbTbeHgTKcCeHHzLpL/0) around it the query results the same as in [PostgreSQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ppwLfTTyNHnBM5juA7MhFd/1). (this is example i've copy/paste from a other comment i made on stackoverflow) and use that as subquery to innerjoin to get the other columns

Comment: Besides i advice you to read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example an expected results.

Answer (score 1):

"select * from friends where iduser in(select GROUP_CONCAT(idFriend) form user u JOIN friends f where f.iduser = u.id and u.id= $uid) AND id NOT IN(select GROUP_CONCAT(id) from friends where iduser = $id)";

: I think this will help you . Let me know if you are facing any issues with this.
: I have updated the query.

Comment: i can directly tell it will not work..  `... id NOT IN(select GROUP_CONCAT(id) ...` won't work..

Comment: any specific reason @RaymondNijland

Comment: Because it not works how you think it will work `GROUP_CONCAT(id)` returns a comma separted string by defualt which **can't** be trusted with `[NOT] IN(..)` operators with int datatype columns to compare.. [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fLrbTBB7UnBJmd5nErgUDH/0) is what you are basically are doing in the `... id NOT IN(select GROUP_CONCAT(id) ...` part here.